# Configuring Eclipse JPA DDL Generation to generate a SQL delimiter

Tags: eclipse, jpa, eclipselink, ddl, dali

Is there a way to configure Eclipse JPA DDL generation to specify a trailing ';' for each statement on the output file?
For example:

```
CREATE TABLE PHYSICAL_OBJECT (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))
```

would become

```
CREATE TABLE PHYSICAL_OBJECT (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

Comment: What platform are you using? EclipseLink, Hibernate?

Comment: EclipseLink.  In the Eclipse JPA Perspective I Right-click the JPA project in the Project Explorer and select JPA Tools > Generate Tables from Entities.  The resulting SQL DDL doesn't have any statement terminination, e.g., the ;.  I've looked through the JPA Preferences dialog but don't see any way to specify this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606825/problems-with-generating-sql-via-eclipselink-missing-separator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with generating sql via eclipseLink - missing separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606825/problems-with-generating-sql-via-eclipselink-missing-separator)