# EclipseLink does not generate terminate statement for OraclePlattform

Tags: eclipselink

When generating the schema generation script, the terminate statement ";" is generated correctly when using a h2 database, but no terminate statement is generated for oracle. (eclipselink.ddlgen-terminate-statements is set to true)

Is there any way to make eclipselink generate ";"? Really want to avoid going through the script afterward and add ";" manually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606825/problems-with-generating-sql-via-eclipselink-missing-separator) shortly after having posted the question....  Basically,

- Create a subclass of `OraclePlatform`
- set the protected field `storedProcedureTerminationToken` to `;`
- Use its qualified name for the property `eclipselink.target-database`